# check if the number inside arraay in object

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

how to make new array of the date and time which not picked on the date which available  for this case ?

and the case is something like this

```js
const theNumOne = [
    {
      date: "monday",
      time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00", "09.00", "10.00"]
    },
    {
      date: "tuesday",
      time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00", "09.00", "10.00"]
    },
    {
      date: "wednesday",
      time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00", "09.00", "10.00"]
    }
]

const pickOne = [
    {
      date: "monday",
      time: ["09.00", "10.00"]
    },
    {
      date: "wednesday",
      time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00"]
    }
]
```

the result would be like this

```
[
 {
  date: "monday",
  time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00",]
 },
  {
   date: "tuesday",
   time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00", "09.00", "10.00"]
  }
 {
  date: "wednesday",
  time: ["09.00", "10.00"]
 }
]
```

the result is the time which not includes on theNumOne in pickOne, 
like say i pick monday on 09.00 and 10.00 
but i did not pic the time from 6- 8 
so i want put that 6-8 and the day into that array of object

i have tried this

```
const result = []
for( let i of theNumOne){
  for(let j of i.time){
    for(let z of pickOne){
      for(let x of z.time){
        if(i !== z ){
          result.push({
            date: i,
            time: z
          })
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why does Wednesday in your result have `09:00` when it also in the `pickOne` list?

Comment: i tried to  2 nested loop for that but the result is is not the same like i want, and this algorthm too difficult for me, sorry

Comment: @MarkMeyer just fixed, sorry

Answer (score 1):

```
const theNumOne = [
    {
        date: "monday",
        time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00", "09.00", "10.00"]
    },
    {
        date: "tuesday",
        time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00", "09.00", "10.00"]
    },
    {
        date: "wednesday",
        time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00", "09.00", "10.00"]
    }
];

const pickOne = [
    {
        date: "monday",
        time: ["09.00", "10.00"]
    },
    {
        date: "wednesday",
        time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00", "09.00"]
    }
];

// get  theNumOne date and time,  pickOne date and time, this function iterates the theNumOne array get's the
// first record, iterates the pickOne array and founds it's date key match,
// sends the theNumOne date and time, and the matched record from pickOne, to remove the unwanted time


const iterateArray = (theNumOne, pickOne) => {

    theNumOne.map((pointer, index) => {

        const extractedRecord = pickOne.find( key => key.date === pointer.date );
        purifyingArray(theNumOne[index], extractedRecord);

    })


};

const purifyingArray = (theNumOne, extractedRecord) => {

    if(extractedRecord !== undefined) {

        extractedRecord.time.map((pointer) => {

            let index = theNumOne.time.indexOf(pointer);

            if(index > -1) {
                theNumOne.time.splice(index,1);
            }
    });

}
console.log(theNumOne);


};


iterateArray(theNumOne, pickOne);
```

Answer (score 0):

The filtering of times within an object can be achieved by using a combination of [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

The following solution loops through all the provided days, and filters the time array. It searches for the day key in the `pickOne` array, if it was found the `time` array is used to check the time values from `theNumOne`

Possible solution:

```js
const theNumOne = [
    {
      date: "monday",
      time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00", "09.00", "10.00"]
    },
    {
      date: "tuesday",
      time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00", "09.00", "10.00"]
    },
    {
      date: "wednesday",
      time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00", "09.00", "10.00"]
    }
]

const pickOne = [
    {
      date: "monday",
      time: ["09.00", "10.00"]
    },
    {
      date: "wednesday",
      time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00"]
    }
];

const results = theNumOne.map(day => ({
    ...day,
    time: day.time.filter(time => {
        const dayFilter = pickOne.find(pickOneDay => pickOneDay.date === day.date);
        return dayFilter === undefined ? true : dayFilter.time.indexOf(time) === -1 
    })
}))

console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is much more efficient then what you did:

I defined a function to find the difference between two arrays (credit to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4026828/3729184) answer, I just modified it a little), and just reassigned `time`.

```js
const theNumOne = [{
    date: "monday",
    time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00", "09.00", "10.00"]
  },
  {
    date: "tuesday",
    time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00", "09.00", "10.00"]
  },
  {
    date: "wednesday",
    time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00", "09.00", "10.00"]
  }
];

const pickOne = [{
    date: "monday",
    time: ["09.00", "10.00"]
  },
  {
    date: "wednesday",
    time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00"]
  }
];

function diff(a, b) {
  return a.filter(function(i) {
    return b.indexOf(i) < 0;
  });
};
let results = [];
for (i in theNumOne) {
  results.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(theNumOne[i])));
  for (j in pickOne) {
    if (results[i].date == pickOne[j].date)
      results[i].time = diff(results[i].time, pickOne[j].time);
  }
}

console.log(results)
```

Comment: The usage of `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` to copy an object is kinda hacky. Object Spread has been introduced to cleanly and performantly copy an object.

Answer (score 0):

Try This!!!

```
 const theNumOne = [
    {
        date: "monday",
        time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00", "09.00", "10.00"]
    },
    {
        date: "tuesday",
        time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00", "09.00", "10.00"]
    },
    {
        date: "wednesday",
        time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00", "09.00", "10.00"]
    }
];

const pickOne = [
    {
        date: "monday",
        time: ["09.00", "10.00"]
    },
    {
        date: "wednesday",
        time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00"]
    }
];
let ResultArray =theNumOne ;

ResultArray.forEach((theNumOneElement,i) => {
    pickOne.forEach(pickOneElement => {
        if (theNumOneElement.date === pickOneElement.date) {
            ResultArray[i].time = theNumOneElement.time.filter(val => !pickOneElement.time.includes(val));
            //array1 = array1.filter(val => !array2.includes(val));
        }
    });
});
console.log(ResultArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

This one should do the trick:

```js
const theNumOne = [
    {
      date: "monday",
      time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00", "09.00", "10.00"]
    },
    {
      date: "tuesday",
      time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00", "09.00", "10.00"]
    },
    {
      date: "wednesday",
      time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00", "09.00", "10.00"]
    }
];

const pickOne = [
    {
      date: "monday",
      time: ["09.00", "10.00"]
    },
    {
      date: "wednesday",
      time: ["06.00", "07.00", "08.00", "09.00"]
    }
];
var result = [];
found_dt = false;
for (var el_opt in theNumOne) {
   found_dt=false
   for (var el_pick in pickOne) {
      if(pickOne[el_pick].date == theNumOne[el_opt].date) {
         result.push({date: theNumOne[el_opt].date, time: theNumOne[el_opt].time.filter(x => !pickOne[el_pick].time.includes(x))});
         found_dt=true
      }
   }
   if(!found_dt) {
      result.push({date: theNumOne[el_opt].date, time: theNumOne[el_opt].time})
   }
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```